# Scala child case class param name conflict with parent case class param name

Tags: scala, parameters, case-class

Let us assume we have the two following classes:

```
abstract case class MyParent(param: Int) {
   // ...
}

case class MyChild(param: Int) extends MyParent(param: Int) {
   // ...          ^^^^^                        ^^^^^
}
```

Making them both case classes resulted in an error in both `param` usage places, which says that it needs the `override` modifier that will override the value from the parent class. This looks strange to me.. why do I have to invent other param names here.. why is this order of things enforced? Where is the profit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never should derive a case class from another case class!

Try this in a REPL started with *scala -deprecation*:

```
scala> case class Foo(foo: String)
defined class Foo

scala> case class Bar(override val foo: String) extends Foo(foo)
<console>:9: warning: case class `class Bar' has case ancestor `class Foo'.  Case-to-case inheritance has potentially dangerous bugs which are unlikely to be fixed.  You are strongly encouraged to instead use extractors to pattern match on non-leaf nodes.
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix for that is to do this

```
abstract case class MyParent(param: Int) {
   println("Form parent : " + param)
}

case class MyChild(override val param: Int) extends MyParent(param) {
   println("Form child : " + param)
}

val c = MyChild(10);
```

This will result in this

```
>> From parent : 10 
>> From child : 10
```

Actually the `extends MyParent()` is not like in Java. This is a way to tell `MyChild` extends `MyParent`, and call the super constructor of the latter at first.

Answer (score 1):

> Where is the profit?

Simply the lack of a not-too-useful special case. `param` in `case class MyChild(param: Int)` is a class member as well as a constructor parameter, so one of ancestors already has a (non-abstract) `param` member, it has to be overridden. And Scala requires `override` keyword when overriding everywhere else, so it requires it here as well.

Answer (score 1):

As far as my limited Scala knowledge goes, case classes are typically used for immutable algebraic data types and pattern matching. Therefore, instead of creating a "child class", you should probably instead create a class which *contains* the "parent" class.

```
> case class MyParent(param: Int)
defined class MyParent

> case class MyChild(param: Int, parent: MyParent)
defined class MyChild

> def foo(c: MyChild) = c match {
    case MyChild(p, MyParent(p2)) => println("p: " + p + ", p2 " + p2)
  }
foo: (c: MyChild)Unit

> foo(MyChild(3, MyParent(4)))
p: 3, p2 4
```